# Position colorbox relative to a parent div

Tags: css, colorbox, css-position

Is there any way I can position my [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) relative to a parent div? I need it to appear to the right of a specific element and not in a position relative to the entire page.

Answer (score 2):

After the dom has loaded, you can move the #colorbox element.  Example:

```
$('#colorbox').appendTo('#newElement');
```

Then, when you assign colorbox to an element, you'll want to specify a position instead of letting it try to center itself in the visitors viewport.

```
$('a.example').colorbox({top:0, right:0});
```

And of course your parent object will need to have positioning so that colorbox is positioned relative to it.

```
#newElement { position:relative; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="outer" style="position: relative">
   <div id="inner" style="positon: relative"></div>
</div>
```

Here **#inner** element is positioned relatively to **#outer** element. It means that you can make #outer element position absolute or fixed and place it where you want. #inner always will be relative to #outer.

Comment: yes I understand the general concept I am just not sure how to apply it to the colorbox which always seems to have the body tag as its parent regardless of where I place the inline divs in the document...